# File upload with grails and jquery

Tags: jquery, grails

I have a form with multiple inputs plus a doc or pdf file upload.

```
//Multiple input fields are here then upload ->
<div class="controls">
    <div class="fileupload ${ person?.attachment ? 'fileupload-exists' : 'fileupload-new' }" id="attachment" data-provides="fileupload" data-name="attachment">
        <span class="btn btn-file">
            <span class="fileupload-new">Add</span>
            <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
            <input type="file" />
        </span>
        <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
        <a href="#" class="close fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload" style="float: none">×</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the form is submitted with jquery

```
$(document).on('click', "#submit", function () {
    //TODO Take the chosen file and upload it with form data
    //Taking data from form and contructing a object and posting it with ajax
}
```

I can't figure out how to upload the doc/pdf file with the form when `#submit` is pressed.

Client side upload is taken from [here](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/2.3.1/javascript.html).

I've looked at `g:form` and `g:uploadForm` but I wouldn't really wanna use them as they seem to refresh the page and/or redirect the user.

Comment: Are you able to get the file object in your params at controller end?

Comment: No, I tried to send it with `$("#attachment").find('input')` but this has just the header and length of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below function to send files with ajax on form submit 
at view end

```
        function formSubmit(){

           var formData=new FormData($('form#create-form')[0]);
            $.ajax({url: 'createAttachment', type:'POST', data: formData, processData: false,contentType: false,dataType: 'script',success:function(result){

            }});
            return false
        }
```

at controller side use below code to access file objects

```
def createAttachment = {
    List attachmentsFiles=[]
    request.fileNames.each {
        def singleFile = request.getFile(it)
        if(singleFile.getOriginalFilename()) {
            attachmentsFiles.add(singleFile)
        }
    }
    attachmentsFiles.each { file ->
       println(file.getOriginalFilename())
    }
  //put your code here
}
```

**attachmentsFiles** will have all uploaded files.

Comment: My form has `<div class="form-horizontal">form elements</div>` no `<form>` tags so the form data would not work in this case?

Comment: You can simply create object of FormData() and append data to it as well
`var formData =new FormData();
formData.append('file', document.getElementById('file').files[0]);`

Comment: Another problem I get the file but other form data does not want to convert back to it's model.

`formData.append('file',document.getElementById('uploadedFile').files[0]);
formData.append('person',person);`

Files arrive as multipart and the person arrives as generic Object

Comment: you can send id of that object formData.append('person',person.id);

Comment: Ooh that is nice! Thank you so much.